# Wordpress Get Posts not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display 6 posts from a specific custom post type in Wordpress. Everything is working, except for when I remove the line "$wp_query = new WP_Query();". When missing that line, 20 posts gets displayed in alphabetical order and I have no idea why. wp_reset_postdata() or wp_reset_query() don't seem to do anything.

```
<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query( ); ?>

<div class="blog-footer row margin-top">
    <?php

    global $post;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'blog', 'posts_per_page' => 6 );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                </a>
            </div>
    <?php endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();?>
</div>
```

Happy to get any inputs on why this behaves the way it does. Appreciate it!

Comment: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)

Answer (score 0):

`global $post` is a global variable mostly used by wordpress itself and is used to get contents/ attributes of current post or page mostly..
Read details here

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post

try below code.

```
<div class="blog-footer row margin-top">
    <?php
    wp_reset_query() ;        
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'blog', 'posts_per_page' => 6 );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $myposts as $b_post ) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
            <a href="<?php $b_post->post_name; ?>">
                <?php 
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $b_post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image[0] ?>"/>
                <h4><?php $b_post->post_title; ?></h4>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php } 
    wp_reset_postdata();?>
</div>
```